# Подскажите, правильно ли расставлены запятые в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Вo вpeмя исследoвaния, 826 жeнщин в вoзрaсте от 18 дo 39 лет, у кoторыx рaнeе cлучалиcь неoбъяснённыe повтoрныe выкидыши и кoтoрые aктивнo пытaлиcь зaберeменеть, были oтoбрaны cлучaйным oбразoм для ежeднeвного приёмa либо 400 мг прoгестерoнa, либо плaцебo, вплoть до 12-й нeдeли берeменнoсти.

Answer (score 1):

Не нужна запятая после «во время исследования». Это просто обстоятельство времени, можно заменить: «При исследовании 826 женщин были отобраны...».
Вообще в случаях, подобных этому, когда предложение сильно «закручено», необходимость постановки знаков препинания можно определить, во-первых, «стягиванием» предложения (отбрасывайте то, без чего предложение по-прежнему не потеряет смысла — смотрите, как я выше убрал большую конструкцию «в вoзрaсте от 18 дo 39 лет, у кoторыx рaнeе cлучалиcь неoбъяснённыe повтoрныe выкидыши и кoтoрые aктивнo пытaлиcь зaберeменеть, ...»). Во-вторых, если сомневаетесь, пробуйте заменять слова синонимичными (особенно это помогает с предлогами, когда «во время исследования» можно заменить на «при исследовании», «несмотря на холод» можно заменить, например, на «даже в холодную погоду» — искушение принять конструкцию за деепричастный оборот сразу пропадает). Подчеркну, что второй приём (замена) работает не всегда, в отличие от первого, но иногда помогает лучше разобраться в сути предложения.

Comment: Я тоже хотел сказать, что первая запятая лишняя, но не написал ответ, п. ч. не мог понять, чем обосновать последнюю запятую. Только тем, что без неё "до 12-й недели" можно отнести **только** ко второму "либо", что будет неправильно?

Comment: _Menelion Elensúlë: «несмотря на холод» можно заменить, например, на «даже в холодную погоду» — искушение принять конструкцию за деепричастный оборот сразу пропадает…_ === Да, не деепричастный оборот, но... См. http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=413#pp413 § 75… Оборот со словами **несмотря на** может не обособляться **только в случае**, если он стоит непосредственно после глагола: _Он это сделал несмотря на запрет врачей (ср.: Несмотря на запрет врачей, он это сделал)_.

Comment: **Артём**, да, думаю, именно этим (потому что если «выкинуть» этот кусок, запятая действительно не нужна).

Comment: **slava1947**, да, согласен с вами! Просто ничего умнее на ум не пришло именно про предложные конструкции. Но замена таки да часто работает именно с предлогами)

Answer (score 0):

А еще можно сложнозакрученное предложение разбить на два попроще:

> В исследoвaнии участвовало 826 жeнщин в вoзрaсте от 18 дo 39 лет, у кoторыx рaнeе cлучалиcь неoбъяснённыe повтoрныe выкидыши и кoтoрые aктивнo пытaлиcь зaберeменеть. Они были cлучaйным oбразoм разделены на две группы для ежeднeвного приёмa либо 400 мг прoгестерoнa, либо плaцебo, вплoть до 12-й нeдeли берeменнoсти.